# What are the possible real eigenvalues of $A^2 + I_n$ , where A is an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

(A) $0,2$

(B) $2$

(C) $−1,1$

(D) $1$

Think answer is D but don't know.

This was the thinking provided: 
[image: original work]

However I have come to the conclusion:
[image: Correct Solution]

Confirmed that B is the correct answer :)

Comment: welcome to maths stackexchange. Can you include the reason why do you guess the answer is $D$? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 also reference for mathjax here.

Comment: for an orthogonal matrix, A^2=I, and A^2+In=In+In = 2In, therefore eigenvalue is 1?

Comment: @omlivylu You should include your thoughts in the question.

Comment: then the reasonable choice would be $(A)$ or $(B)$ rather than $D$ isn't it? anyway, for an orthogonal matrix, $A^TA=I$. you might like to include your reasoning in your post. to start using mathjax, lesson $1$ would be to surround mathy objects with dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. Verify if $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is orthogonal.
2. Verify if $A=1$ is orthogonal.

Remark:

Orthogonal matrix means $A^TA=I$ rather than $A^2=I$.

Definition of eigenvalue and eigenvector:

For a square matrix $A$, a non-zero vector, $v \neq 0$ is called the eigenvector if $\exists \lambda$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. The $\lambda$ is known as the eigenvalue.

Hence if we let $B=A^2+I$ and you have shown that $\exists v$, $Bv=2v$, the right conclusion is $2$ is an eigenvalue, there might be other eigenvalues as well.

Comment: first matrix is orthogonal

Comment: yup. let that matrix be $A$. compute $A^2+I$ and find the eigenvalue.

Comment: wow thanks so much I understand it well now :)

Comment: Redid the problem and got B just before your response :D

Comment: btw, you might like to click on edit and include your thoughts there, knowing what you are thinking helps the volunteers to know your confusion accurately. Don't be discouraged by the downvoting. We just want to keep the site quality higher that everyone include their thoughts in their posts whenever possible.

Comment: btw, are you sure the answer is $B$?

Comment: what is the matrix $A^2+I$ that you obtain fron the first hint?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

Use the fact that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$, where $f$ is some polynomial. Now what do we know about the eigenvalues of a orthogonal matrix?

Comment: we know it is ±1

Comment: Now use the first part of the hint

Comment: Be careful, A might have a complex eignevalues, but we can be sure that $|\lambda| = 1$

Comment: Just wasn't sure if it was just 1 eigenvalue as opposed to 2 (pos and neg values)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Anyway here's another hint. The problem reduces to finding $f(\lambda)$, where s.t. $\lambda^2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $| \lambda | = 1$. You should be able to bring it over the line from here.

Comment: thank you for your help